# How do I replace text containing network location?

Tags: xml, powershell, replace

I am trying to have a Powershell script that would read out all manually mapped network drives , export to xml, then read the xml, change the path value, then create a new xml file with the new values, delete the current mapped network drives and create new drives using the same letters but new paths from the new xml file.

So far it worked when I only change the domain name for example or one of the subfolders, but when i want to change the entire path (like \server1.domain.com\dept\folder to \server2.newdomain.org\deptnew\folder1) then it just doesn't change it. below is the entire code:

```
    # Save the mapped drives
$networkdrivespath= $tempspecial + "C:\Users\ITADMIN\Desktop\netdrives.xml" #Output location for XML of current drives
$drives = get-psdrive
$networkdrives = @()
foreach ($drive in $drives)
    {
    $root = Out-String -InputObject $drive.DisplayRoot   
    $name = Out-String -InputObject $drive.Name
    
    if ($root.StartsWith("\\"))
        {
        $root =$root.Substring(0,$root.Length -2)
        $name = $name.Substring(0,$name.Length -2)
        $networkdrive = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        Add-Member -InputObject $networkdrive -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Driveletter" -Value $name
        Add-Member -InputObject $networkdrive -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Path" -Value $root
        $networkdrives +=$networkdrive
        }
    }
Export-Clixml -InputObject $networkdrives -Force -Path $networkdrivespath #Mapped drives to be saved in XML

$old = "\\domain1.com\dept\folder\user\subfolder"
$new = "\\domain2.org\dept1\subfolder\user\subfolder"

#(Get-Content -path C:\Users\ITADMIN\Desktop\netdrives.xml -Raw) -replace "\\domain1.com\dept\folder\user\subfolder","\\domain2.org\dept1\subfolder\user\subfolder"| Set-Content -Path C:\Users\ITADMIN\Desktop\output.xml # should change the path

(Get-Content -path C:\Users\ITADMIN\Desktop\netdrives.xml -Raw) -replace ($old, $new) | Set-Content -Path C:\Users\ITADMIN\Desktop\output.xml # Tried it variables as well


net use * /delete /y #Delete existing mapped drives


$networkdrivespath = $temppath + "C:\Users\ITADMIN\Desktop\output.xml" #imports the new changed XML
$netdrives = Import-Clixml -Path $networkdrivespath
foreach ($netdrive in $netdrives)
{
    $driveletter = $netdrive.Driveletter.tostring() + ":"
    if (!(test-path $driveletter))
    {
        New-PSDrive -Name $netdrive.Driveletter.tostring() -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $netdrive.Path.tostring() -Persist
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason in particular you are using XML over other formats? XML is a bit harder to use in PowerShell in my experience. You should probably not be doing regex replace on the raw file contents and rather traversing the XML structure if you want to modify an XML file. Also, you have the drive as an easily navigable object before writing to the XML file, why don't you just use that object? Do you need to store it as XML in the interim? Otherwise you're creating a lot of problems for yourself by doing it this way, I think.

Comment: Well to be honest I wouldn't mind an easier of doing things. The reasoning behind exporting an XML file was to keep a copy of the current mapped drives' locations before manipulating anything, so that in case any user faces a problem connecting to the new location/drive, at least we have some sort of backup showing us what the users had before the script was run. Final intention is to have it running as a logon script and the users wouldn't really notice a change, same drive letters just different destinations after the file migration is done. Ideas are welcome :)

Comment: There isn't a super easy way to give you an answer here. You will need to learn a little more about how powershell works. You will want to navigate the objects using things like Foreach-Object, Where-Object, Get-Path, Resolve-Path, Split-Path, etc... 

When you make the changes you need to the $drive object then you can use the New-PSDrive command to create it as you were doing before.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

That line

```
(Get-Content -path C:\Users\ITADMIN\Desktop\netdrives.xml -Raw) -replace ($old, $new) | Set-Content -Path C:\Users\ITADMIN\Desktop\output.xml # Tried it variables as well
```

has to be switched to

```
(Get-Content -path C:\Users\ITADMIN\Desktop\netdrives.xml -Raw) -replace ([regex]::Escape($old), $new) | Set-Content -Path C:\Users\ITADMIN\Desktop\output.xml # Tried it variables as well
```